# Different results to the same to the same sum (C language) (Round-off problem)

Tags: c, vector, sum, double

Well, I'm trying to sum a vector using two different methods. The results should be the same but that doesn't happen.

**Method 1:** the vector is summed in a linear way;

**Method 2:** the vector is summed in two parts;

The code is presented bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,n;
    double a,b,c;
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
    n=1000000;

//Initialization
    double vec[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        vec[i]=1.0001;
    }

//Sum Method 1
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a+=vec[i];
    }

//Sum Method 2
    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        b+=vec[i];
    }
    for(i=n/2;i<n;i++)
    {
        c+=vec[i];
    }
    b=c+b;

    //------------------------------------ 
    printf("Method 1: %.30f\n",a);
    printf("Method 2: %.30f\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Method 1: 1000099.999976676190271973609924316406
Method 2: 1000100.000003988854587078094482421875
```

Is There any way to solve this problem?

Comment: C floating point math in not exact. The order of operations might affect the outcome (as you observe).

Answer (score 1):

Floating point addition is not associative.
In the first one you add up like: (((x1 + x2) + x3) + x4). While in the second like (x1 + x2) + (x3 + x4).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't 30 digits of precision in a `double`, so using `%.30f` isn't too meaningful.

A `double` has a fractional part that is about 52 binary bits. Or, about 16 decimal digits.

As others have mentioned, floating point isn't precise and order of operations can affect the outcome.

Better to see how far off the two results are, as a percentage of the "ideal" (i.e. `a`).

I've added this to your program. The results are:

```
Method 1: 1000099.9999766761902720
Method 2: 1000100.0000039888545871
dif: -0.0000273126643151
pct: -0.0000000027309933
```

So, the difference is about 2 billionths of 1 percent.

But, this is slightly misleading. Notice that `a` and `b` are off by about `0.00002` *but* with the integer part using 7 digits, this means about 12 digits.

In other words, the two methods are [for all practical purposes] equivalent within the expected precision and order of operations.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int i,
     n;
    double a,
     b,
     c;

    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    n = 1000000;

//Initialization
    double vec[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vec[i] = 1.0001;
    }

//Sum Method 1
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a += vec[i];
    }

//Sum Method 2
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        b += vec[i];
    }
    for (i = n / 2; i < n; i++) {
        c += vec[i];
    }
    b = c + b;

    // ------------------------------------
    printf("Method 1: %.16f\n", a);
    printf("Method 2: %.16f\n", b);

    double dif = a - b;
    printf("dif: %.16f\n", dif);

    double pct = dif / a;
    pct *= 100;
    printf("pct: %.16f\n", pct);

    return 0;
}
```